# How does --save-config work with resource definition?

Tags: kubernetes

With the below yml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-nginx
    image: nginx:alpine
```

---

On running `kubectl create -f nginx.pod.yml --save-config`, then as per the [documentation](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_create/): `If true, the configuration of current object will be saved in its annotation.`

Where exactly is this annotation saved? How to view this annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below command would print all the annotations present in the pod `my-nginx`:

```
kubectl get pod my-nginx  -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations}'
```

Under `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration` of the above output, your configuration used is stored.

Here is an example showing the usage:

Original manifest for my deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: my-deploy
  name: my-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-deploy
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: my-deploy
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

Created the deployment as follow:

```
k create  -f x.yml --save-config
deployment.apps/my-deploy created

kubectl get deployments.apps my-deploy   -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations.kubectl\.kubernetes\.io\/last-applied-configuration}' |jq .
{
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "metadata": {
    "annotations": {},
    "creationTimestamp": null,
    "labels": {
      "app": "my-deploy"
    },
    "name": "my-deploy",
    "namespace": "default"
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "app": "my-deploy"
      }
    },
    "strategy": {},
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "app": "my-deploy"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "image": "nginx",
            "name": "nginx",
            "resources": {}
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "status": {}
}

kubectl get deployments.apps my-deploy   -o jsonpath='{.spec.template.spec.containers[*].image}'
nginx
```

Now some user came and changed the image on nginx from `nginx` to `httpd`, using `imperative` commands.

```
k set image deployment/my-deploy nginx=httpd --record
deployment.apps/my-deploy image updated


kubectl get deployments.apps my-deploy   -o jsonpath='{.spec.template.spec.containers[*].image}'
httpd
```

However, we can check that the last applied declarative configuration is not updated.

```
kubectl get deployments.apps my-deploy   -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations.kubectl\.kubernetes\.io\/last-applied-configuration}' |jq .
{
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "metadata": {
    "annotations": {},
    "creationTimestamp": null,
    "labels": {
      "app": "my-deploy"
    },
    "name": "my-deploy",
    "namespace": "default"
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "app": "my-deploy"
      }
    },
    "strategy": {},
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "app": "my-deploy"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "image": "nginx",
            "name": "nginx",
            "resources": {}
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "status": {}
}
```

Now, change the image name in the original manifest file from `nginx` to `flask`, then do `kubectl apply`(a declarative command)

```
kubectl apply -f orig.yml
deployment.apps/my-deploy configured
kubectl get deployments.apps my-deploy   -o jsonpath='{.spec.template.spec.containers[*].image}'
flask
```

Now check the last applied configuration annotation, this would have `flask` in it. Remember, it was missing when `kubectl set image` command was used.

```
kubectl get deployments.apps my-deploy   -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations.kubectl\.kubernetes\.io\/last-applied-configuration}' |jq .
{
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "metadata": {
    "annotations": {},
    "creationTimestamp": null,
    "labels": {
      "app": "my-deploy"
    },
    "name": "my-deploy",
    "namespace": "default"
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "app": "my-deploy"
      }
    },
    "strategy": {},
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "app": "my-deploy"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "image": "flask",
            "name": "nginx",
            "resources": {}
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "status": {}
}
```

**Where is the "last-applied" annotation saved:**

Just like everything else, Its saved in `etcd` , created the pod using the manifest provided in the question and ran `raw` etcd command to print the content. (in this dev environment, etcd was not encrypted).

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt get /registry/pods/default/my-nginx
/registry/pods/default/my-nginx
k8s

v1Pod⚌
⚌
                                                                                                                                                                   my-nginxdefault"*$a3s4b729-c96a-40f7-8de9-5d5f4ag21gfa2⚌⚌⚌b⚌
0kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration⚌{"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Pod","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"my-nginx","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"containers":[{"image":"nginx:alpine","name":"my-nginx"}]}}
```

Comment: Are the annotations stored in `etcd`?

Comment: Does `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration` automatically get re-used upon existing running Pod, when I run `kubectl apply nginx-updated.pod.yml`

Comment: about `etcd` I am not 100% certain, but seems like the case.  About 2nd question(if I understood the question) , yes. the annotation will update with latest config data when apply is done again.

Comment: I would like to understand, what is the advantage of storing last configuration? How different it is to apply `kubectl apply` without storing last configuration...

Comment: @overexchange, added some more info on `Where exactly is this annotation saved?`, not sure if its relevant anymore or not.